# Two threads with two executables (.dis) files Limbo(Programming Language)

Tags: multithreading, executable

Can not understand how to do two processes (process 1 and 2) are implemented separately executable files and exchange messages. Something like (1.Hello 2.Hi 1.How are you ? ...).

The code below illustrates how the two threads exchanging messages from text files. 
Necessary that instead of text files become executable files (.dis) that communicate with each other messages.

```
implement LThread;
include "sys.m";
include "bufio.m";
include "draw.m";

sys:Sys;
FD: import Sys;
stOut: ref Sys->FD;

bufio:Bufio;
Iobuf:import bufio;  

LThread:module{
    init: fn(nil: ref Draw->Context, nil: list of string);

    process: fn(pName: string); 
};

init(nil: ref Draw->Context, nil: list of string) {
    sys=load Sys Sys->PATH; 
    bufio=load Bufio Bufio->PATH;

    spawn process("processA.txt");
    sys->sleep(10);
    spawn process("processB.txt");
}
process(pName: string) {

    file_buf:ref Iobuf;
    file_buf = bufio->open(pName, sys->ORDWR);

    temp_line:string;
    temp_line=" ";

    while (temp_line != nil){
    temp_line=file_buf.gets('\n');
    sys->sleep(200);
    sys->print("%s \n",temp_line);
    }   
}
```

Perhaps with the help of modules, i do not know.

Comment: The code have the 2 processes implemented and you need to know how it's done? You say that the code shows 2 threads, from what I can see there are 2 processes there..can you be more specific what the code does and what is your issue?

Comment: I need to call the 2 process of two executable files, and that these processes work in parallel 
I do not know how to call the executable files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I wanted. Its own interface has the type of a Command module, and that is the type of the things it executes.

On lines of exec, cmd is set to the first of the words in the argument list, and the string .dis is concatenated to it (to account for the fact that Limbo object program files are conventionally named using this suffix).
information was taken: "The Limbo Programming Language".

```
exec(ctx: ref Draw->Context, args: list of string){
        c: Command;
        cmd,file: string;

        cmd = hd args;      

        file = cmd + ".dis";
        c = load Command file;
        if(c == nil)
            c = load Command "/dis/"+file;

        if(c == nil) {
            sys->print("%s: not found\n", cmd);
            return;
        }
        c->init(ctx, args);
}
```